# Listing all files in directory: How to detect if a result is a file or a subdirectory?

Tags: sas

I have a small STP which list all files/subdirectories in a given directory on our Unix-Server.
Problem is, my datastep only returns the name of the object, but not an information if this is a file or directory.

I tried some things and had some Ideas, but non is really foolproof, maybe someone can give me a hint how i can get this.

What i have tried so far:

- using fileexists: This returns true for files and directories, so this does not work here
- Checking for a dot. There could be files without extensions (and so dont have a dot) and also directories which have a dot in name, so this is not foolproof
- using unixfunctionalities in sas: This is forbidden on our server, so no option for me
- open an filehandle and do a finfo, this returns a warning if it is not a file, but

  a)maybe it could be something else then a directory or file, or a warning because of other reasons

  b)checking for a warning to detect type is not a good solution imo

Here a part of my code which i am using:

```
filename _folder_ "%bquote(&mydirectory/)";
data x (keep=filepath);
  handle=dopen( '_folder_' );
  if handle > 0 then do;
   count=dnum(handle);
   do i=1 to count;
    filepath="&mydirectory"||dread(handle,i);
    output;
   end;
  end;
  rc=dclose(handle);
run;
filename _folder_ clear;

/*this part just makes a macrovariable with all results*/
proc sql noprint;
  select filepath into: fpath separated by '#' from x;
quit;

/* this macro collects some additional fileinformation from all file in macrovariable fpath and creates a HTML-Ouput*/
%FileAttribs;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FILENAME()` function to define a fileref to the file. This will return a code to indicate if the file exists or not. Then use the `DOPEN()` function to attempt to open the fileref as a directory. This will tell you if the file is a directory.

For example here is the function style macro that I use.

```
%macro direxist
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Test if directory exists
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
(path    /* Name of directory to test for existance */
);
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Test if directory exists. Returns value 1 or 0.
 1 - Directory exists
 0 - Directory does not exist

Global macro variable SYSRC will be set to 1 when a file is found
instead of a directory.

----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
%local return rc did fileref;
%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Set up return values as normal failure to find path.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
%let return=0;
%let sysrc=0;

%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
If path is not specified or does not exist then return normal failure.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
%if (%bquote(&path) = ) %then %goto quit;
%if ^%sysfunc(fileexist(&path)) %then %goto quit;

%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Try to open it using DOPEN function.
Return 1 if it can be opened.
Otherwise set SYSRC=1 to mean that PATH exists but is not a directory.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
%if (0=%sysfunc(filename(fileref,&path))) %then %do;
  %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&fileref));
  %if (&did) %then %do;
    %let return=1;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
  %end;
  %else %let sysrc=1;
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fileref));
%end;

%quit:
%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Return the value as the result of the macro.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
&return
%mend;
```

Comment: Ty, that worked for me, already had a filename and fopen in my macro, but did not get the idea to check the fid